# Deploy Public Key in Windows Server

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, public-key, private-key

I have a Windows server in AWS and I want to deploy a public key to connect sftp authentication by key file.

I use freeftpd to reach my sftp connection but the program do not support key authentication so I try to get the connection in another sftp client(Filezilla,WinSCP,etc) but when I try to connect with the key it is unable to use key file.

The public key is format like:
ssh-rsa AAAABBBCCCDDD appadm@host11
How can I deploy the public key for allow only 1 User through sftp connection?
Thanks

Comment: you need an SSH server on Windows that supports authentication with ssh keys, such as Reflection SSH, OpenSSH for Windows, Cygwin, FreeSSHd etc;

Answer (score 1):

did you deploy a SSH server in your AWS server?

Remember, SFTP uses SSH protocol, Not FTP, which in windows doesn't come out of the box.

You can check this [Link](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server) to guide you in the process of setting up a SSH server using openSSH